# Opposite of Attribute Contains Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have the following list:

```
<ul>
    <li class="x anotherclass"></li>
    <li class="y"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="z"></li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="y"></li>
</ul>
```

I wold like to select all list items which do not have a class of `y`.

Is there an opposite command for the attribute contains selector?

```
$("ul li[class*='y']") // Is there an opposite, maybe as in *!=...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [not](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector for that.

example:

```
$("ul li:not([class*='y'])")
```

Comment: +1: I got so side-tracked looking to somehow combine the `!` with the selector `*=`, it never occurred to me to check for `:not`. I'm accepting this answer as it according to the time-stamp was the first answer posted which did solve my problem.

Comment: Thanks that's very fair of you! Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Try this: `$('ul li').not('.y')`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this selector:

```
$("ul li:not([class*='y'])")
```

Documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul li').siblings().not('.y');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery [:not() Selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/).